# How to pass the customer id dynamically in the tap payment method to save the card value

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, tap-payment

I am sending the `post` request to the **TAP PAYMENT GATEWAY** in order to save the card, the `url` is expecting two parameters like one is the source (the recently generated token) and inside the `url` the `{customer_id}`, I am trying the `string` concatenation, but it is showing the error like *Invalid `JSON` request.*

**views.py:**

```
ifCustomerExits = CustomerIds.objects.filter(email=email)
totalData = ifCustomerExits.count()
if totalData > 1:
    for data in ifCustomerExits:
        customerId = data.customer_id
        print("CUSTOMER_ID CREATED ONE:", customerId)
    tokenId = request.session.get('generatedTokenId')
    payload = {
        "source": tokenId
    }

    headers = {                        
        'authorization': "Bearer sk_test_**********************",
        'content-type': "application/json"
    }

    # HERE DOWN IS THE url of TAP COMPANY'S API:

    url = "https://api.tap.company/v2/card/%7B"+customerId+"%7D"
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    json_data3 = json.loads(response.text)
    card_id = json_data3["id"]
    return sponsorParticularPerson(request, sponsorProjectId)
```

**Their expected url** = [https://api.tap.company/v2/card/{customer_id}](https://api.tap.company/v2/card/%7Bcustomer_id%7D)

**Their documentation link:** https://tappayments.api-docs.io/2.0/cards/create-a-card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..
First convert `dict`. into `JSON` and send `post` request with `request.post`:

```
    import json
    ...
    customerId = str(data.customer_id)
    print("CUSTOMER_ID CREATED ONE:", customerId)
    tokenId = request.session.get('generatedTokenId')
    payload = {
        'source': tokenId
    }

    headers = {                        
        'authorization': "Bearer sk_test_**************************",
        'content-type': "application/json"
    }
    pd = json.dumps(payload)
    # HERE DOWN IS THE url of TAP COMPANY'S API:

    url = "https://api.tap.company/v2/card/%7B"+customerId+"%7D"
    response = requests.post(url, data=pd, headers=headers)
    json_data3 = json.loads(response.text)
    card_id = json_data3["id"]
    return sponsorParticularPerson(request, card_id)
```

Please tell me this works or not...

Comment: thank a lot Sir, it progressed a little bit, at least it is now sending the request properly, now it is showing the error status as below, may be it is due to, that I am using the dummy security keys like sk_test...
ERROR MESSAGE:
{'status': 'fail', 'type': 'card_not_saved', 'message': 'Failed to save the card'}

Comment: @USAMAREHMANYOUSAF You are welcome. I never used `TAP PAYMENT GATEWAY`. But every payment gateway provide test secret key and private key. Go to to your payment gateway dashboard and generate **test** secret key.See this : [API KEY](https://tappayments.api-docs.io/2.0/authentication/api-keys) and [API OVERVIEW](https://tappayments.api-docs.io/2.0/api/api-overview)

Comment: Sir it is now working properly, thanks for your help...!